# Reading files get stuck in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am running this command on my log files,

```
grep "." file | tr '|' '\n' | sed -r "s/(.{3}).*?\.cpp/\1TRY/g" | tr '\n''|'
```

It runs as expected i.e. keeping the first three letters same to files with `.cpp` extension, adds `TRY` to it.

So if input is: `abcdef.cpp`

```
ouput is: abcTRY
```

(keeping words without extension as it is)

But is stops running(gets stuck) after some time, any suggestions on what might be the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the non-greedy quantifier.

```
sed -r "s/^(.{3})[^.]*\.cpp/\1TRY/"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me what was the problem?

Comment: there isn't a non-greedy thing in sed. `.*?` .